# Systemd networking service fails because of unknown interface

Tags: networking, systemd, usb, network-interface

My problem is related to USB tethering and network interfaces.

When I run `ifconfig -a`, normally I see 3 interfaces - loopback, WiFi and Ethernet. I have defined gateway, netmask and broadcast for each one of them in `/etc/networking/interfaces`.

Sometimes I connect my phone to my machine for USB tethering and when running `ifconfig -a` I can see 1 more interface called `enp0s20u2`. This interface is shown only when the phone is connected and USB tethering is enabled in it. In order to bring up that interface, I've added the following lines in `/etc/networking/interfaces`:

```
# For USB tethering
auto enp0s20u2
iface enp0s20u2 inet dhcp
    address 192.168.42.56
    gateway 192.168.42.1
    netmask 255.255.255.0
    broadcast 192.168.42.255
```

This way, When I connect my phone, this interface is automatically brought up and configured.

**The problem** is that the systemd service can't start if the phone is not connected. The `enp0s20u2` interface is unknown most of the time, Therefore `systemctl` fails to bring it up on startup as well as when I manually run `systemctl restart networking`.

Is there a way to assure this interface configuration won't make the service fail to start?

Comment: You should not keep an interface that is not always present as `auto`.  Yet, removing `auto` will create the problem that you will need to perform the `ip link enp0s20u2 up` command by hand.  To not run it by hand you may be able to setup a `ifplugd` service but then it if `ifplugd` that will fail on startup.  A better option may be `nmcli` (NetworkManager).

Comment: This general approach should work for you: http://evadeflow.com/2012/11/automatically-configuring-a-usb-ethernet-adapter-on-embedded-linux/

Answer (score 1):

Replacing the `auto` directive with `allow-hotplug` takes care of this gracefully. The interface will no longer be brought up by `ifup -a` (and therefore not by the `systemd` `networking` service), but it will be brought up via `udev` when it is plugged in, or detected at boot.

```
# For USB tethering
allow-hotplug enp0s20u2
iface enp0s20u2 inet dhcp
    address 192.168.42.56
    gateway 192.168.42.1
    netmask 255.255.255.0
    broadcast 192.168.42.255
```

From `man 5 interfaces`:

> Lines beginning with "allow-" are  used  to  identify  interfaces  that
> should  be  brought  up automatically by various subsytems. This may be
> done using a command such as "ifup --allow=hotplug  eth0  eth1",  which
> will  only  bring up eth0 or eth1 if it is listed in an "allow-hotplug"
> line. Note that "allow-auto"  and  "auto"  are  synonyms.   (Interfaces
> marked "allow-hotplug" are brought up when udev detects them.  This can
> either be during boot if the interface is  already  present,  or  at  a
> later  time,  for  example when plugging in a USB network card.  Please
> note that this does not have anything to do with  detecting  a  network
> cable being plugged in.)